# How do I process Proxy Digg JSON for use with jQuery?

Tags: json, api, proxy, jsonp, digg

I'm trying to deal with: "Requests made from Javascript running on your web pages must be proxied to avoid same-origin policy conflicts."

I know how to work with the JSON once I've got it. But aside from copy-pasting the JSON results via my browser, I don't know how to localize it for use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data){
//do smth with data
})
```

?

After the request is complete, `data` will be an object with all JSON response and you can access it as regular js object: `data.something` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't answer my question. Note that if you replace "URL" with:

http://services.digg.com/stories/popular?count=3&appkey=http://www.blah.com/application&type=json

You won't pull any data. This url will work in the browser, but not through javascript.